# laravel localhost/public/index.php doesn't show background image and svgs, but "php artisan serve" shows them

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have a small beautiful laravel project on my pc.

On the `welcome.blade.php` file, it has a background image. And the image is located on

> public/images/

directory.

I have used this following CSS to call and represent them:

```
html, body {
color: #f4f6f7;
font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;

background-image: url('/images/back.png');
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

This project contains a favicon icon too, and this is located as per laravel designed.

> The problem is:

When I go to `localhost/got/public/index.php` form my chrome

**it loads my project but can not show or load background image or favicon icon.**

But when I run `php artisan serve` 
it runs well with no problem.

What is the things i am missing?

Comment: Your path differ when you use `localhost/got/public/`. Try make a virtual host for your project.

Comment: great. Thank You. That worked...
But I wonder, why!

Comment: you're welcome. Look at the answer for the `why` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path differ when you use `localhost/got/public/`. Try make a virtual host for your project.

Well, here's the WHY part. When you use artisan serve, the image path (that is RELATIVE: /images/back.png) refers to `http://localhost:8000/images/back.png`. And when you use your local server the images refers to `http://localhost/images/back.png` again BUT your address is `localhost/got/public/images/back.png`.

Comment: I am wondering to deploy it on LIVE. 
what could happened ?
as there is no internal change, will it work well on live server?

Comment: The benefit of using virtual host is that you can ensure that your local project works ALMOST seamlessly on host. I said almost because some  aspects (for example file upload) may has some incompatibility based on local OS. And if my answer helped  please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: yeah your answer solved my problem. I am late because i was thinking which answer should i take.

Answer (score 2):

please use this :

```
background-image: url('{{ asset('images/back.png') }}');
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I tried this but my editor, may be something is wrong...

this is not working...

Answer (score 2):

Try to add following code to your `webpack.mix.js`

.options({
        processCssUrls: false,
  })

Comment: in where should I include this?

Comment: you will find webpack.mix.js in your laravel-project's root.

Answer (score 1):

When loading your header files, including the .css files use `{{ asset("filesurl")  }}`